# For how long does the AVPlayer continues to buffer from an URL after a pause?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection, avplayer

I was reading the [AVPlayer class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and I couldn't find the answer for my question.

I'm playing a streamed audio from the Internet on my iPhone app and I'd like to know if after a `[myAVPlayer pause];` invocation `myAVPlayer` will keep downloading the audio file on the background for a long time.

If the user pushes the **"Pause"** button, invoking  `[myAVPlayer pause];` and then leaves the app, will `myAVPlayer` keep downloading a large amount of data?

I'm concerned about this when the user is on 3G Network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am faced with the same question and have done some experimentation. My observations are only valid for video, but if they are also valid for audio, then AVPlayer will try to buffer around 30s of content when you press pause. If you have access to the webserver, you could run tcpdump/wireshark and see how long after you press pause that the server continues to send data.

Comment: Great! I'll run Wireshark on that!

Answer (score 0):

You can manage how long AVPlayer continues to buffer.
You need to manage **preferredForwardBufferDuration** of avplayer currentItem. If you want to stop buffering set value to 1 because if you set it to 0 it will be set up automatically

```
self.avPlayer.currentItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 1;
```

**From Apple documentation:** This property defines the preferred forward buffer duration in seconds. If set to 0, the player will choose an appropriate level of buffering for most use cases. Setting this property to a low value will increase the chance that playback will stall and re-buffer, while setting it to a high value will increase demand on system resources.